# Criação de controles dinamicos em ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Estou querendo criar um componente para um cadastro padrão. No projeto em que estou desenvolvendo, estou utilizando Web Forms, onde eu tenho a minha masterPage com o layout do site (menu, cabeçalho e rodapé). Mas para facilitar a manutenção futura, criei uma classe e dentro dela criei um método onde esta pagina crie dinamicamente os meus botões, titulo desse cadastro e assim por diante. Porém quando vou fazer a chamada dele da minha pagina de cadastro de clientes por exemplo, ocorre um erro porque o meu panel do cadastro de cliente ainda não foi criado:

> Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Código do meu cadastro de grupo:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /****************************
        *   Declarando os Objetos   *
        ****************************/

        CadastroPadrao cp = new CadastroPadrao();
        Grupo gp = new Grupo();

        /********************************************
        *   Metodo que cria os objetos na pagina    *
        ********************************************/

        cp.GeraCadastro("Cadastro de Grupo", gp);                           
    }
```

Codigo da minha classe Padrao:

```
    public void GeraCadastro(string titulo, Object tela) 
    {
        Button btnPesquisar = new Button();

        btnPesquisar.Text = "Pesquisar";
        btnPesquisar.ID = "btnPesquisar";
        btnPesquisar.Width = 100;

        if (Convert.ToString(tela) == "TulipaCB.Grupo")
        {
            CadastroPadrao pagina = new CadastroPadrao();

            pagina.pnBotao.Controls.Add(btnPesquisar);
        }
```

Erro ocorre no momento exato em que roda a linha:

`pagina.pnBotao.Controls.Add(btnPesquisar);`

Comment: Acho que seu botão não tem ViewState. Com isso, a página perde o botão a cada post - o botão que você a cada carga da página não é o botão que estava lá antes. Dá um ViewState pro botão que você cria e vê se resolve.

Comment: Parece que a propriedade `pnBotao` está nula, você pode mostrar o código da classe `CadastroPadrao`?

Comment: esse meu pnBotao, eu crio na pagina .aspx:

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CadastroPadrao.aspx.cs" Inherits="TulipaCB.Cadastro.CadastroPadrao" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h2>
            <asp:Literal ID="ltTitulo" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID ="pnBotao" runat="server"> </asp:Panel>    
    </div>   
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID ="pnGrid" runat="server"> </asp:Panel>    
    </div> 
</asp:Content>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver a minha situação... Eu usei o User Control, nele eu desenho como eu quero os botoes,grid e tudo mais. Isso funciona como um componente, depois de pronto é só arrastar para a tela e pronto :)

Caso alguém precise tem o passo a passo aqui:

http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/277/aspnet-utilizando-usercontrols.aspx